# Is Intel_MKL supposed to populate the include folders, etc, on MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, intel-mkl

I've installed Intel MKL and it shows in dropdown menu of VS 2017 and VS 2019. Everything seems fine, except I have to manually type in the locations of include and library files. Did I misconfigure something?

What works for me is to explicitly add the include folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.245\windows\mkl\include
```

and library folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.245\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win
```

However, I do note that MKL_ROOT is not defined as an environment variable by "default". If I run

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.245\windows\mkl\bin\mklvars.bat intel64
```

then after that MKL_ROOT is defined and the PATH includes the library locations and, I guess, if I then launch MSVC from the commmand line then it should probably work. But I was hoping this would all be automated, somehow. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Tunneller,

The ease of MKL setup in Visual Studio depends on how you installed it. [This article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-configuring-the-microsoft-visual-c-c-development-system-to-link-with-intel-mkl) explains how to do manual linking of MKL to VS if you did not install the integration component. And [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-automatically-linking-your-microsoft-visual-c-c-project-with-intel-mkl) explains how to invoke the automatic linking if you did install the integration component.

The above articles refer to the Intel Parallel Studio installation. It may differ if you install MKL as a standalone component or via Intel System Studio.

I hope this helps.

Pamela